# Need to get record count by passing 2 parameter values and record_type='VALID' using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, tibco

I Have a XML document like below. i need to get record count for each LOCATION_NAME and FILE_TYPE when record_type='VALID'. LOCATION_NAME and FILY_TYPE are in Parameters. for that two parameters, i have to get the record count when the RECORD_TYPE='VALID'.

i will be providing one LOCATION_NAME and one FILY_TYPE for each iteration (loop) and need to get count. Input parameters will be passed by external system (Tibco JDBC QUERY result in this case).

```
<root>
<SellOutRecord>
    <FILE_TYPE>STOSO</FILE_TYPE>
    <RECORD_TYPE>VALID</RECORD_TYPE>
    <RECORD_NO>1</RECORD_NO>
    <LOCATION_NAME>XYZ el</LOCATION_NAME>
</SellOutRecord>
<SellOutRecord>
    <FILE_TYPE>STOSO</FILE_TYPE>
    <RECORD_TYPE>ERROR</RECORD_TYPE>
    <RECORD_NO>2</RECORD_NO>
    <LOCATION_NAME>XYZ el</LOCATION_NAME>
</SellOutRecord>
<SellOutRecord>
    <FILE_TYPE>STOSO</FILE_TYPE>
    <RECORD_TYPE>VALID</RECORD_TYPE>
    <RECORD_NO>3</RECORD_NO>
    <LOCATION_NAME>XYZ el</LOCATION_NAME>
</SellOutRecord>
<SellOutRecord>
    <FILE_TYPE>STOSO</FILE_TYPE>
    <RECORD_TYPE>WARNING</RECORD_TYPE>
    <RECORD_NO>3</RECORD_NO>
    <LOCATION_NAME>XYZ el</LOCATION_NAME>
</SellOutRecord>
<SellOutRecord>
    <FILE_TYPE>STOSO</FILE_TYPE>
    <RECORD_TYPE>ERROR</RECORD_TYPE>
    <RECORD_NO>4</RECORD_NO>
    <LOCATION_NAME>XYZ el</LOCATION_NAME>
</SellOutRecord>
<SellOutRecord>
    <FILE_TYPE>STOSO</FILE_TYPE>
    <RECORD_TYPE>ERROR</RECORD_TYPE>
    <RECORD_NO>6</RECORD_NO>
    <LOCATION_NAME>XYZ XYZ</LOCATION_NAME>
</SellOutRecord>
<SellOutRecord>
    <FILE_TYPE>STOSO</FILE_TYPE>
    <RECORD_TYPE>VALID</RECORD_TYPE>
    <RECORD_NO>7</RECORD_NO>
    <LOCATION_NAME>XYZ XYZ</LOCATION_NAME>
</SellOutRecord>
<SellOutRecord>
    <FILE_TYPE>STOSO</FILE_TYPE>
    <RECORD_TYPE>VALID</RECORD_TYPE>
    <RECORD_NO>8</RECORD_NO>
    <LOCATION_NAME>XYZ XYZ</LOCATION_NAME>
</SellOutRecord>
<SellOutRecord>
    <FILE_TYPE>STOSO</FILE_TYPE>
    <RECORD_TYPE>ERROR</RECORD_TYPE>
    <RECORD_NO>9</RECORD_NO>
    <LOCATION_NAME>XYZ XYZ</LOCATION_NAME>
</SellOutRecord>
<SellOutRecord>
    <FILE_TYPE>STOSO</FILE_TYPE>
    <RECORD_TYPE>VALID</RECORD_TYPE>
    <RECORD_NO>10</RECORD_NO>
    <LOCATION_NAME>XYZ XYZ</LOCATION_NAME>
</SellOutRecord>
<InventoryRecord>
    <FILE_TYPE>STOIV</FILE_TYPE>
    <RECORD_TYPE>ERROR</RECORD_TYPE>
    <RECORD_NO>2</RECORD_NO>
    <LOCATION_NAME>XYZ el</LOCATION_NAME>
</InventoryRecord>
<InventoryRecord>
    <FILE_TYPE>STOIV</FILE_TYPE>
    <RECORD_TYPE>VALID</RECORD_TYPE>
    <RECORD_NO>4</RECORD_NO>
    <LOCATION_NAME>XYZ el</LOCATION_NAME>
</InventoryRecord>
<InventoryRecord>
    <FILE_TYPE>STOIV</FILE_TYPE>
    <RECORD_TYPE>VALID</RECORD_TYPE>
    <RECORD_NO>5</RECORD_NO>
    <LOCATION_NAME>XYZ el</LOCATION_NAME>
</InventoryRecord>
<InventoryRecord>
    <FILE_TYPE>STOIV</FILE_TYPE>
    <RECORD_TYPE>ERROR</RECORD_TYPE>
    <RECORD_NO>8</RECORD_NO>
    <LOCATION_NAME>XYZ XYZ</LOCATION_NAME>
</InventoryRecord>
<InventoryRecord>
    <FILE_TYPE>STOIV</FILE_TYPE>
    <RECORD_TYPE>ERROR</RECORD_TYPE>
    <RECORD_NO>9</RECORD_NO>
    <LOCATION_NAME>XYZ XYZ</LOCATION_NAME>
</InventoryRecord>
<InventoryRecord>
    <FILE_TYPE>STOIV</FILE_TYPE>
    <RECORD_TYPE>VALID</RECORD_TYPE>
    <RECORD_NO>11</RECORD_NO>
    <LOCATION_NAME>XYZ XYZ</LOCATION_NAME>
</InventoryRecord>
<InventoryRecord>
    <FILE_TYPE>STOIV</FILE_TYPE>
    <RECORD_TYPE>VALID</RECORD_TYPE>
    <RECORD_NO>14</RECORD_NO>
    <LOCATION_NAME>XYZ XYZ</LOCATION_NAME>
</InventoryRecord>
<SalesInRecord>
    <FILE_TYPE>STOSI</FILE_TYPE>
    <RECORD_TYPE>VALID</RECORD_TYPE>
    <RECORD_NO>1</RECORD_NO>
    <LOCATION_NAME>XYZ el</LOCATION_NAME>
</SalesInRecord>
<SalesInRecord>
    <FILE_TYPE>STOSI</FILE_TYPE>
    <RECORD_TYPE>ERROR</RECORD_TYPE>
    <RECORD_NO>2</RECORD_NO>
    <LOCATION_NAME>XYZ el</LOCATION_NAME>
</SalesInRecord>
<SalesInRecord>
    <FILE_TYPE>STOSI</FILE_TYPE>
    <RECORD_TYPE>VALID</RECORD_TYPE>
    <RECORD_NO>3</RECORD_NO>
    <LOCATION_NAME>XYZ el</LOCATION_NAME>
</SalesInRecord>
<SalesInRecord>
    <FILE_TYPE>STOSI</FILE_TYPE>
    <RECORD_TYPE>WARNING</RECORD_TYPE>
    <RECORD_NO>3</RECORD_NO>
    <LOCATION_NAME>XYZ el</LOCATION_NAME>
</SalesInRecord>
<SalesInRecord>
    <FILE_TYPE>STOSI</FILE_TYPE>
    <RECORD_TYPE>ERROR</RECORD_TYPE>
    <RECORD_NO>4</RECORD_NO>
    <LOCATION_NAME>XYZ el</LOCATION_NAME>
</SalesInRecord>
<SalesInRecord>
    <FILE_TYPE>STOSI</FILE_TYPE>
    <RECORD_TYPE>ERROR</RECORD_TYPE>
    <RECORD_NO>7</RECORD_NO>
    <LOCATION_NAME>XYZ XYZ</LOCATION_NAME>
</SalesInRecord>
<SalesInRecord>
    <FILE_TYPE>STOSI</FILE_TYPE>
    <RECORD_TYPE>VALID</RECORD_TYPE>
    <RECORD_NO>8</RECORD_NO>
    <LOCATION_NAME>XYZ XYZ</LOCATION_NAME>
</SalesInRecord>
<SalesInRecord>
    <FILE_TYPE>STOSI</FILE_TYPE>
    <RECORD_TYPE>WARNING</RECORD_TYPE>
    <RECORD_NO>8</RECORD_NO>
    <LOCATION_NAME>XYZ XYZ</LOCATION_NAME>
</SalesInRecord>
<SalesInRecord>
    <FILE_TYPE>STOSI</FILE_TYPE>
    <RECORD_TYPE>ERROR</RECORD_TYPE>
    <RECORD_NO>10</RECORD_NO>
    <LOCATION_NAME>XYZ XYZ</LOCATION_NAME>
</SalesInRecord>
</root>
```

for example if i provide 
1. LOCATION_NAME=XYZ XYZ and FILE_TYPE='STOSI' then i should get valid_rec_count=1
2. LOCATION_NAME=XYZ el and FILE_TYPE='STOIV' then i should get valid_rec_count=2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Use**:

```
count(/*/*[RECORD_TYPE='VALID']
            [FILE_TYPE = $pfileType and LOCATION_NAME = $pLocname]
     )
```